# Remove stop button in slides.js?

Tags: javascript, jquery, slideshow

slides.js has virtually no documentation. I've got it set to automatically change the slide, and have the prev/next buttons hidden. Is there a way to also hide the "stop/play" button?

Answer (score 7):

```
$(function () {
    $("#slides").slidesjs({
        play: {
            active: false, /* this hides the stop/play button */
            auto: true,
            interval: 5000,
            swap: true
        }
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

use display none property of css

for example if your play button class is `".play"` then put in css

```
.play
{
 display:none;
}
```

Comment: I don't think I've got a play button class, I've just got the images inside `<div id="slides">` inside `<div class="container">`. I've tried `.play`, `.slidesjs-play`, etc.

Comment: Turns out it's `play: {active: false}` in the jQuery